# SQLite Database table never created

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm trying to create a SQLite Database but run into a problem that seems to derive from the table CONTACTS never being created (I get the error message 'Error while inserting 'no such table: CONTACTS'
').

From the code below, can anyone see what is wrong and how it can be corrected? This example is taken straight from this guide, which is why I'm surprised it doesn't work:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_6_iPhone_Application

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{  
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    // Get the documents directory

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    //Buid the path for database file
    _databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                     initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.db"]];

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *db_path = [_databasePath UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_open(db_path, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;

            const char *sql_stmt =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(_contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                _text.text = @"Failed to create table";
            }
            sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
        } else { 
            _text.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
        }
    }

}

- (IBAction)saveName:(id)sender {


NSString *currentName = self.text.text;
NSString *nameSaved = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:currentName];


    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"pass");
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name) VALUES (\"%@\")",
                               nameSaved];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, insert_stmt,
                           -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
        NSLog(@"pass");
        } else {
        NSLog( @"Error while inserting '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(_contactDB));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);

    }  
}
```

Comment: You might want to remove the app from you device/simulator and re-run the app because if you ever ran this code previously but the create fable failed, the db would stay in your documents folder (and thus you'd never hit your create table statement again).

Comment: The following line doesn't look good.  NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name) VALUES (\"%@\")",nameSaved]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that code - it runs fine here on Mac OS X and in the iOS simulator. Does the error come later when you try and insert data into the table? Are you closing the file before trying to insert data into it?

Run it in the simulator, step through the code, and then find the file in the simulator's Documents directory. Use Terminal to see what's in the file:

```
sqlite3 path-to-file .dump
```

The exact path will differ on your machine but in my iOS simulator I get:

```
sqlite3 "/Users/my-login-name/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/DAD0BB47-2136-4367-8DAF-AA578D0C00A5/Documents/contacts.db" .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT);
COMMIT;
```

You can see that the table exists with the correct columns.

Comment: Yes, the error occurs when I try to insert data into the table (saveName method in the code above). So I guess the error is somewhere there then..I'm just not sure what it is.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the other routine. That code runs fine here too under the simulator. I am able to insert data and view it later. Are you sure self.text.text contains the string you want to add? If nothing else, delete the app from the simulator and try again. Maybe Rob is right and the existing file isn't valid for some reason. Check it with the sqlite3 dump command to see what the table looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Use `objectAtIndex`:

```
sqlite3*    _contactDB;
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

// Get the documents directory

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

//Buid the path for database file
  NSString *  _databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                     initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
{
    const char *db_path = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_open(db_path, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;

        const char *sql_stmt =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT)";

        if (sqlite3_exec(_contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to create table") ;
        }
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
    } else { 
       NSLog( @"Failed to open/create database");
    }
}
```

Comment: While objectAtIndex can be used, there's nothing wrong with [0] in recent versions of Objective-C.

Comment: why -ve vote code is working fine on my system (base sdk Mac osx 10.5)